# Android Image U and V buffers too large

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm reading the YUV values from a android image using the camera2 api. Hence I have the 3 planes.

```
for (int x = 0; x < imageSheaf[0].Width; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < imageSheaf[0].Height; y++)
    {
        imageYuv[x, y] = new yuv();
    }
}


for (int j = 0; bufferY.HasRemaining; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rowStrideY/2; i += 2)
    {
        if (i > width / 2 - 1 || j > height / 2 - 1)
            Log.Info("Processing", "Out of Bounds");
        imageYuv[i, j].y = bufferY.Get();
        bufferY.Get();//skip a pixel due to 4:2:0 sub sampling
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rowStrideY/2; i++)//skip a line due to 4:2:0 sub sampling
    {
        bufferY.Get();
        bufferY.Get();
    }

    if (!bufferY.HasRemaining)
        Log.Debug("Processing", "finished");
}

for (int j = 0; bufferU.HasRemaining; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rowStrideU; i++)
    {
        if (!bufferU.HasRemaining)
            Log.Debug("Processing", "finished");
        imageYuv[i, j].u = bufferU.Get();
    }

    if (!bufferU.HasRemaining)
        Log.Debug("Processing", "finished");
}

for (int j = 0; bufferV.HasRemaining; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rowStrideV; i++)
    {
        if (!bufferV.HasRemaining)
            Log.Debug("Processing", "finished");
        imageYuv[i, j].v = bufferV.Get();
    }

    if (!bufferV.HasRemaining)
        Log.Debug("Processing", "finished");
}
```

This is the code that I'm using to get the Y, U and V values from the byte buffers.

The ImageFormat is YUV_420_888, It is my understanding that the 4:2:0 subsampling means that for every U or V pixel there is 4 Y pixels.

My issue is that the size of the byte buffers for the U and V planes are larger than they should be causing array out of bounds exceptions:

```
[Processing] RowstrideY = 720
[Processing] RowstrideU = 368
[Processing] RowstrideV = 368
[Processing] y.remaining = 345600, u.remaining = 88312, v.remaining = 88312
```

(the size of the image is 720x480)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YUV420 has 8 bits per pixel for Y, and 8 bits per four-pixel group for U and V.  So at 720x480, you'd expect the U-V plane to be 360x240.

However, the actual hardware may have additional alignment or stride restrictions.  In this case, it appears the hardware requires the stride to be a multiple of 16, so it increases it from 360 to 368.

You'd expect that to turn into a length of 368*240=88320, but remember, the last eight bytes on every line are simply padding.  So the buffer can actually be (368*239)+360 = 88312 bytes without omitting any data.  If you're getting array-bounds exceptions it's because you're attempting to read the end-of-row pad bytes from the last line, but that's not allowed.  The API only guarantees that you will be able to read the data.

The motivation for this is that, if the padding on the last line happened to cross a page boundary, the system would need to allocate an additional unnecessary page for each buffer.

You can modify your code to copy the data bytes from each row, then have a second loop that just consumes the padding bytes (if any) at the end of the row.

Comment: Would it be likely that the multiple of 16 stride to occur for all devices? or just my testing device?

Comment: It will vary from device to device, but multiples of 16 are pretty common. Some devices may not require alignment, some might require 8 or 32.